# How optimize jquery hide/show list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How **optimize** `jQuery` **hide/show** list?

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#call_ads").click(function() {
                $("#ads").toggle("slow");
                $("#chats").hide("slow");
                $("#all-active-ads").click(function() {
                    $(".active_ads").show("slow");
                    $(".inactive_ads").hide("slow");
                    $(".all_ads").hide("slow");
                });
                $("#all-inactive-ads").click(function() {
                    $(".inactive_ads").show("slow");
                    $(".active_ads").hide("slow");
                    $(".all_ads").hide("slow");
                });
                $("#all-ads").click(function() {
                    $(".all_ads").show("slow");
                    $(".inactive_ads").hide("slow");
                    $(".active_ads").hide("slow");
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav admin-navbar">
  <li id="call_ads"><a><span class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></span> | Skelbimai</a></li>
  <li id="call_discussions"><a><span class="fa fa-commenting-o"></span> | Diskusijos</a></li>
  <li id="call_news"><a><span class="fa fa-rss"></span> | Straipsniai</a></li>
  <li id="call_paid_ads"><a><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> | Reklamos</a></li>
  <li id="call_chats"><a><span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span> | Susirašinėjimai</a></li>
  <li id="call_mods"><a><span class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></span> | Moderatoriai</a></li>
  <li id="call_users"><a><span class="fa fa-user-o"></span> | Vartotojai</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- in admin header -->


<!-- in view -->
<div class="active_ads" style="display: none;">
  <h1 class="text-centert">Patvirtinti skelbimai</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Pavadinimas</th>
        <th>E. Paštas</th>
        <th>Paskelbtas</th>
        <th>Vartotojas</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($active_ads as $active_ad) : ?>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>
          <?= $active_ad['id']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $active_ad['title']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $active_ad['email']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $active_ad['created_at']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $active_ad['active']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="inactive_ads" style="">
  <h1 class="text-centert">Nepatvirtinti skelbimai</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Pavadinimas</th>
        <th>E. Paštas</th>
        <th>Paskelbtas</th>
        <th>Vartotojas</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($inactive_ads as $inactive_ad) : ?>
      <tr class="warning">
        <td>
          <?= $inactive_ad['id']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $inactive_ad['title']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $inactive_ad['email']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $inactive_ad['created_at']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $inactive_ad['active']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="all_ads" style="display: none;">
  <h1 class="text-centert">Visi skelbimai</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Pavadinimas</th>
        <th>E. Paštas</th>
        <th>Paskelbtas</th>
        <th>Vartotojas</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($ads as $ad) : ?>
      <tr class="info">
        <td>
          <?= $ad['id']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $ad['title']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $ad['email']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $ad['created_at']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $ad['active']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You have event handlers inside of event handlers. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would like to automatically hide other ids. if click on #call_ads and click on his child other childs automatically hide, if click on all-active auto hide others call childrens (all-inactive,all-ads) and etc.

Comment: now my code is works fine, but i want optimize it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For More optimization :-
Try this

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#call_ads").click(function() {
                $("#ads").toggle("slow");
                $("#chats").hide("slow");
                $("#all-active-ads,#all-ads,#all-inactive-ads").click(function() {
                    $(".inactive_ads , .all_ads,.active_ads").hide("slow");
                    if($(this).attr('id')=='all-inactive-ads'){
                        $(".inactive_ads").show("slow");
                    }else if ($(this).attr('id')=='all-active-ads'){
                        $(".active_ads").show("slow");
                    }else if ($(this).attr('id')=='all-ads'){
                        $(".all_ads").show("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

**Edit**:-
Try this

```
function() {
        $("#call_ads").on('click',function() {
            $("#ads").toggle("slow");
            $("#chats").hide("slow");
            $("#all-active-ads,#all-ads,#all-inactive-ads").on('click',function() {
                $(".inactive_ads ,.all_ads,.active_ads").hide("slow");
                if($(this).attr('id')=='all-inactive-ads'){
                    $(".inactive_ads").show("slow");
                }else if ($(this).attr('id')=='all-active-ads'){
                    $(".active_ads").show("slow");
                }else if ($(this).attr('id')=='all-ads'){
                    $(".all_ads").show("slow");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

It will work for you.Just change `.click(function() {` with `.on('click',function() {`

Comment: it works. but is it not possible to optimize that childrens from this group do not need to be written?

Comment: i am not getting *that childrens from this group do not need to be written? * can you explain it ?

Comment: @MantasStanislovaitis can you give HTML structure details ? after that we can help to optimize more

Comment: nice! Maybe you know why it show 2 times?hide that i want hide(good)->show what i need(good)->hide what i need(why?)->show again what i need (but why 2 times?).

Answer (score 0):

**Should be something like this** https://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/6u79bdzy/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="ads">ads</div>
<div id="chats">chats</div>
<div class="active_ads">active_ads</div>
<div class="inactive_ads">inactive_ads</div>
<div class="all_ads">all_ads</div>


<button id="call_ads">call_ads</button>
<button id="all-active-ads">all-active-ads</button>
<button id="all-inactive-ads">all-inactive-ads</button>
<button id="all-ads">all-ads</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#call_ads").click(function() {
                $("#ads").toggle("slow");
                $("#chats").hide("slow");
            });

          $("#all-active-ads").click(function() {
            $(".active_ads").show("slow");
            $(".inactive_ads,.all_ads").hide("slow");
          });
          $("#all-inactive-ads").click(function() {
            $(".inactive_ads").show("slow");
            $(".active_ads,.all_ads").hide("slow");
          });
          $("#all-ads").click(function() {
            $(".all_ads").show("slow");
            $(".inactive_ads,.active_ads").hide("slow");
          });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all the elements that are gonna be clicked and use switch-case. This will optimize as well as make the code readable as well as scalable. `switch-case` is always recommended above `if-else` as `if-else` traverses through

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#call_ads").click(function() {
      $("#ads").toggle("slow");
      $("#chats").hide("slow");
    });

    $("#all-active-ads,#all-inactive-ads,#all-ads").click(function() {
      $(".active_ads,.inactive_ads,.all_ads").hide("slow"); // hide all of them. switch-case will take care of what to show...
      switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'all-active-ads':
          $(".active_ads").show("slow");
          break;
        case 'all-inactive-ads':
          $(".inactive_ads").show("slow");
          break;
        case 'all-ads':
          $(".all_ads").show("slow");
          break;
      }
    });
  });
```